# How to show price for out of stock bundled products?

Tags: price, bundle

when bundled products are out of stock(the individual items) the price on the frontend shows:0.00 in Magento 2.3.4

I poked around in: vendor/magento/module-bundle/Pricing/Price/FinalPrice.php

public function getAmount()

```
  public function getAmount()
{
    if (!$this->minimalPrice) {
        $price = parent::getValue();
        if ($this->product->getPriceType() == Price::PRICE_TYPE_FIXED) {
            $this->loadProductCustomOptions();
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\CustomOptionPrice $customOptionPrice */
            $customOptionPrice = $this->priceInfo->getPrice(CustomOptionPrice::PRICE_CODE);
            $price += $customOptionPrice->getCustomOptionRange(true);
        }
        $this->minimalPrice = $this->calculator->getAmount($price, $this->product);
    }
    return $this->minimalPrice;
}
```

$price returns 0.

Anyone has an idea how to get the regular price to show on frontend instead of 0 for out of bundled products with out of stock items?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you apply the condition like if bundle is out of stock . so showing price

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by that? Please clarify.

Comment: has someone found a solution for this issue? i tried module above on 2.3.5 but it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create new extension with this functionality.

Create file

**Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $result = parent::_toHtml();

        if(!$result) {
            $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
            try {
                /** @var MsrpPrice $msrpPriceType */
                $msrpPriceType = $this->getSaleableItem()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('msrp_price');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
                return $this->wrapResult($result);
            }

            //Renders MSRP in case it is enabled
            $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
            if ($msrpPriceType->canApplyMsrp($product) && $msrpPriceType->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product)) {
                /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
                $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                    MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                    $this->getSaleableItem(),
                    [
                        'real_price_html' => $result,
                        'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                    ]
                );
                $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
            }

            return $this->wrapResult($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

With this you can do the things you want.

Thanks and Happy Coding.

Comment: Hello, thanks, but that doesnt work. The out of stock bundled product still shows 0,00 as price. Magento 2.3.4